# `ImportNode` in Firefox and extracting an element from an `iframe`

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, import

I am trying to understand `importNode` in html using the following example.

Suppose we have a `content.html`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <nav id="sidebar1" class="sidebar">
       Hi there!
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

and a `main.html`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe src='content.html' hidden='true'></iframe>
    <script>
      var idframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
      var oldNode = idframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0];
      var newNode = document.importNode(oldNode, true);
      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(newNode);
      alert("HI!!!");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of Document.importNode is not an object.
var newNode = document.importNode(oldNode, true);
```

What is the proper way to get an element form an iframe and insert it into my html?

Comment: There is no `getElementByTagName()` method.

Comment: @MaratTanalin Is that the problem? I guess then that [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_getelementsbytagname) confused me. But the first line does work.

Comment: @MaratTanalin Element**s**. Sometimes the tiniest things!

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` returns an array-like collection, not a single element. You should access the needed item by index, e.g. `getElementsByTagName("nav")[0]`.

Comment: @MaratTanalin Sorry. Let me update the code.

Comment: @MaratTanalin Done updating the code and the error.

Comment: Where is your JS code placed? Is it just inside `HEAD` element? Is the code inside a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler or similar jQuery's `ready()`?

Comment: @MaratTanalin The `<script>...</script>` is inside the body. Your third question I don't understand. Sorry. I am truly at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access content of the iframe document *after* the iframe document has been loaded. This can be accomplished different ways:

- either by putting your accessing code into `load` handler of the main (that contains `iframe` element) document window,
- or inside a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener of the document loaded in `iframe`.

Below is example of using `load` event of `window` of the main document:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
    var oldNode = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("myNode");
    var newNode = document.importNode(oldNode, true);
    document.body.insertBefore(newNode, document.body.firstChild);
}, false);
```

Otherwise, iframe content is not yet loaded when you try to access it.

See the [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/cph4gjqu/) at JSFiddle (iframe content is placed encoded in the `srcdoc` attribute of the `iframe` just because I'm not aware of ability to create subdocuments at JSFiddle without creating a separate fiddle).

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you are saying. There is a tricky business about when the iframe is loaded and when the javascript is executed. Right? So, I should place the JavaScript at some point that is executed after the iframe. Is this correct? I am not completely sure if you mean that the position of the `<script>...</script>` is relevant. I put the event `window.addEventLis...` inside a `<script>...</script>` inside the body, after the `iframe`. Is this correct?

Comment: It works now. Thanks. But I would like to also understand what was the key change. 1) position of the `<script>...</script>`? 2) The fact that the code is inside an event listener, which is executed after the page has loaded? 3) Both combined?

Comment: It should typically not matter where to put the code that adds `load` event listener (the listener will anyway be called _after_ the document is completely loaded), but it's usually placed inside `HEAD` element (either as JS code or as a link to an external script like `<script src="example.js"></script>`).

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Is this a standard way to delay the importNode, adding it in an event? Seems to be that taking html into html is cumbersome.

Comment: Yes, it is a common practice to use `DOMContentLoaded` of `document` (when just HTML and CSS need to be loaded) and `load` of `window` (when all page resources need to be loaded) for waiting until the page content or its embedded resources are ready to be used. As for frames in particular, they are generally unneeded if what you really need is retrieving some data from the server; [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) is a more modern, usable and preferred way for this.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.There seem to be many ways to manipulate webpages and it can be overwhelming the different tools one can use to do the same thing. I am trying to get a side navigation bar for all the webpages in a mock website. That is why I am trying to import html (the navigation bar) into another.