# Roadmap to import HTML into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

My original goal was to add (to learn how to add) to all pages in a website a sidebar. I am now able to do it, in at least one way, with the use of [some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32924710/importnode-in-firefox-and-extracting-an-element-from-an-iframe).

But I have a slightly more general question.

Assume that we have two pages `main.html` and `other.html`, and that `other.html` contains some element (what is the proper term? node?), say

```
<htmltag id="theid" class="itsclass">
...
</htmltag>
```

[The example has `id` and the `class` in case the explanation is going to make use of them.]

I would like to know what is the proper, or current, or modern way for `main.html` to get this node (element) form `other.html` and add it to its own body.

---

Currently I am doing this: `main.html` has an `iframe` with `src="other.html"` and `hidden="true"`. Then with `iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById` I am capturing the `htmltag` I want, and with `document.importNode` and `document.body.insertBefore` or `document.body.appendChild` I add it to the body.

I heard, though, criticism about using `iframe`.

I heard also about other possible candidates for doing this job (some I have tried only a little, some I haven't began reading about):

1. [Angular imports](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_includes.asp)
2. [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

I heard about import [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/). But also about [it not being supported](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_includes.asp).

3. Other posts in questions talking about jQuery, PHP, or other things running in the server side.
4. **I just learned** about `object` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23789581/5377542). This one seems pretty simple (well, `iframe` seems also simple). Actually I just tried it and it works nicely. Any comments on the suitability of this option?

To much divergent information for a beginner. I would like to do the importing in the simplest, and most current, way that the HTML allows. Hopefully using only HTML and JavaScript, if possible.

Could someone kindly try to give me some orientation?

Comment: About the html tags (4): [http://stackoverflow.com/q/16660559/5230059](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16660559/5230059)

Comment: @RonC Interesting. So, between `iframe` and `object`, the `iframe` is the one closer to the answer.